# Selenium: Type in an autocomplete input in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, input

I'm trying to type into an autocomplete with send_keys command. It succeeds to put the text in the input but fails to open the autosuggest box. When I do it manually the dropdown opens with suggestions.
Here is the code I've :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="geo-location"]/div[1]/input').send_keys('United States')
```

I've tried to type each letter in a send_keys, I also tried to remove some letters using send_keys('\b'), but both attempts failed. How can I simulate a human typing in this kind of inputs?

Here is the source code of the input I'm trying to write into:

```
<div class="geo-location-select  ui-select-container selectize-control single searchable ng-dirty ng-empty ng-touched open" ng-class="{'open': $select.open, 'searchable': $select.searchEnabled, 'not-searchable': !$select.searchEnabled}" id="geo-location" name="geoLocations" ng-model="tad.term" clear-on="UiGeoSelection" on-select="tad.addGeoLocation$($item, $model)" ng-disabled="tad.disabledFn()" disable-default-dropdown="true" style="">
<div class="selectize-input focus" ng-class="{'focus': $select.open, 'disabled': $select.disabled, 'selectize-focus' : $select.focus}" ng-click="$select.open &amp;&amp; !$select.searchEnabled ? $select.toggle($event) : $select.activate()" style="">
<div ng-hide="$select.searchEnabled &amp;&amp; ($select.open || $select.isEmpty())" class="ui-select-match ng-scope ng-hide" ng-transclude="" allow-clear="true" placeholder="Enter location" style="">
<span class="ng-binding ng-scope"></span>
</div>  
<input type="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" class="ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched ng-empty" ng-click="$select.toggle($event)" ng-class="{'ui-select-search-disabled' : !$select.searchEnabled}" placeholder="Enter location" ng-model="$select.search" ng-hide="($select.selected &amp;&amp; !$select.open)" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" aria-label="Select box" style="width: 440px;"></div><div ng-show="$select.open" class="ui-select-choices ui-select-choices ui-select-dropdown selectize-dropdown single ng-scope" repeat="target in tad.geoLocationsSearchResults" refresh="tad.getGeoLocations$($select.search)" refresh-delay="200" style="opacity: 1;">
<div class="ui-select-choices-content selectize-dropdown-content">
<div class="ui-select-choices-group optgroup" role="listbox">
<div ng-show="$select.isGrouped" class="ui-select-choices-group-label optgroup-header ng-binding ng-hide" ng-bind="$group.name"></div>
<!-- ngRepeat: target in $select.items --></div></div></div>
<ui-select-single></ui-select-single>
<input ng-disabled="$select.disabled" class="ui-select-focusser ui-select-offscreen ng-scope" type="text" id="focusser-2" aria-label="Select box focus" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" disabled="">
</div>
```

Thank you,

Comment: you also need to look for <select> and <options> in html dom

Comment: @AshishKamble I don't ever remember seeing a page that uses a SELECT element to represent an autocomplete list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to select the input first with JS then fill it and it my text to open the suggestion list. For those that are struggling like I was, here is the code I used:

Instead of

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[3]").send_keys('Canada')
```

I used

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#geo-location .ui-select-search")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@type='search'])[3]").send_keys('Canada')
```

PS: I've chosen another element to select then the one to type into, but it still works fine.